# How to copy from and to clipboard?

Tags: excel, vba, string, clipboard

I have two codes (with the help of other users):
#1 makes a specific text string using the current range and puts it into the clipboard.
#2 copies from the clipboard, removes some unwanted characters and puts the modified string back to the clipboard.

These codes do not work in some of the company machines.
All have the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library checked.
[image]

**I've read about using the HTML method but I couldn't figure it out.**

Here are the codes:

#1

```vb
Sub x_copiar_nome_arquivo()

    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim arquivo As String
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With Selection.Rows(1).EntireRow
        arquivo = .Range("G1").Value & " - " & Format(.Range("E1").Value, "#000000000")
    End With
    With DataObj
        .SetText arquivo
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
    
ErrorHandler:
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

#2

```vb
Sub y_chave_danfe()
    
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim chave As String
    Dim danfe As String
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    chave = DataObj.GetText
    danfe = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(chave, " ", ""), "/", ""), "-", ""), ".", ""), "_", "")
    With DataObj
        .SetText danfe
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
    
ErrorHandler:
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final version of my question ended up with a code like so:

It gets whatever it's on the clipboard, remove everything keeping only digits (0-9) and puts the new "number" back to the clipboard.

```
Public Sub y_chave_danfe()

Dim atransf As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim chave As Variant
Dim danfe As String
Dim z As Long

danfe = vbNullString
atransf.GetFromClipboard
chave = atransf.GetText

For z = 1 To Len(chave)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(chave, z, 1)) Then
        danfe = danfe & Mid(chave, z, 1)
    End If
Next z

CreateObject("htmlfile").parentWindow.clipboardData.setData "text", danfe

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Afonso

You could try using [late binding](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/early-late-binding/) for `MSForms.DataObject`.

This code should work on all the machines whether or notthey have the appropriate reference.

```vb
Sub y_chave_danfe()
Dim DataObj As Object
Dim chave As String
Dim danfe As String

    Set DataObj = CreateObject( _
                 "new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    chave = DataObj.GetText
    danfe = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(chave, " ", ""), "/", ""), "-", ""), ".", ""), "_", "")
    With DataObj
        .SetText danfe
        .PutInClipboard
    End With

ErrorHandler:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it did not work properly. In my machine it does, others it did not. I changed the code as you showed and it returned two unknown symbols (on both codes). https://imgur.com/9cvVsLz

Comment: How did it not work? Errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: Both codes should return something (#1 a name and a number and #2 just a long number) but they just paste nothing, and I tested pasting on "words" and it shows there two boxes (?)

Comment: If you use the original code does your test work?

Comment: The original code returns the same situation, on my workstation it does just fine, on others, they return nothing (or those boxes).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two programs I wrote that you can use to interact with the Clipboard.

```vb
Function FromClipboard() As String
    'Returns all text currently in the user's clipboard
    Dim CB As Object
    Set CB = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    CB.GetFromClipboard
    FromClipboard = CB.GetText
End Function

Sub IntoClipboard(ByVal Text As Variant)
    'Text is a Variant type for 64-Bit Support, but the content should be a String
    CreateObject("htmlfile").parentWindow.clipboardData.setData "text", Text
End Sub
```

Here's an example of how to use it

```vb
Sub test()
    'Before changes
    MsgBox FromClipboard
    
    'changing the text
    IntoClipboard "Testing"
    
    'After changes
    MsgBox FromClipboard
End Sub
```

That address `1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69` works on Windows but not Mac, if you want it to work on Mac you need to find the correct address for them and then put an If/Else in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. This method worked on my coworkers station. Appreciated.